# How can I test app on Mobile iOS devices using Flutter flet by (Flutter-Dart)

Tags: python, ios, flutter, dart, flet

I came across the ["flet -> Docs -> testing-on-ios"](https://flet.dev/docs/guides/python/testing-on-ios), and it's fascinating to discover that we can test apps on mobile iOS devices using flet-python.

**However, my question is:**
**Can we test a mobile iOS device using Flutter-Dart with "flet"? If we can, How?**

I have multiple applications that I built using Flutter-Dart. If we can test them on mobile iOS using "flet", that would be incredible!

I attempted to use flet-python, but it's challenging to ascertain whether we can test apps using flet on Flutter-Dart on mobile iOS devices. This is because "flet" was developed a year ago, and there is limited community support for it.

Comment: The project's documentation explicitly says that it only supports Python at the moment. But what is wrong with Flutter's inbuilt support for building and running on mobile devices?

Comment: We typically rely on Xcode and TestFlight for iOS app testing. However, with "flet", you can streamline this process, eliminating the need for these tools. Testing iOS apps using "flet" provides a more simplified approach, marking a significant evolution in our testing practices.